# Difficulty understanding API structure

Tags: swift, struct, codable, spoonacular

I'm working on a project where I'm pulling data from an API. I understood the API's structure for an earlier call, but this one is a bit different and is giving me trouble.

Here's an example of what the API call result looks like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0wVh.png

I see it returning an array of steps, each of which has additional data. So here's how I built my structs:

```
struct Instructions: Codable {
    let steps: [Step]
}

struct Step: Codable {
    let number: Int                     // step number
    let step: String                    // step explanation
    let ingredients: [Ingredient]       // ingredients used in this step
    let image: String
}
```

If these are correctly structured, then I guess my question would be how can I access the data of `struct Step`?
I was thinking of going about it like so:

I initialize this: `var result: [Instructions] = []`, then within the cellForRowAt function of UITableVieDataSource, I do: `let stepContents = result[indexPath.row].steps`. This obviously doesn't work, but I'm trying to set stepContents equal to the `step: String` within Step.

Any tips / thoughts would be greatly appreciated — I'm stumped. Thank you!

Edit: clarified that last paragraph.

Comment: `let stepContents = result.steps.[indexPath.row]` instead? If `result` is a `Instructions`, it's unclear what it is currenlty...

Comment: @Larme Sorry about that — result is initialized as... var result: [Instructions] = []

Comment: can you post the actual json, not a picture, it's not clear what is in step

Answer (score 0):

Your Step structure isn't correct since waiting for

> let image: String

but in the server response which you provided via screenshot, you don't have this field.
Since you added it like non-optional, the decoder can't decode it.

try to set an optional type for an image like:

> var image: String?

or remove if not needed